# How can I upgrade APCUPSD to version 3.14.12

Tags: ups

I can't figure out how to upgrade. I did the initial installation using "apt-get install apcupsd" command.  Can anyone give me detailed instructions how to upgrade to version 3.14.12?

Recently I installed APCUPSD (for APC Uninterruptable Power Supply) to automatically shutdown my server (14.04) in the event of a power failure.  Come to find out, there is a bug in version 3.14.10 that causes the UPS to continuously cycle on and off after power is restored. Version 3.14.12 is supposed to fix the issue but being a newbie to linux.

Answer (score 1):

The official mirrors do not have 3.14.12:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=apcupsd

You have to download the [source tarball](http://sourceforge.net/projects/apcupsd/files/apcupsd%20-%20Stable/3.14.12/) and build it yourself.